# Git in Android Studio - How to create commits with two comments

Tags: git, android-studio-2.1

When using Git on the command line, I normally commit two commit messages at once like this:

```
git commit -m"short message" -m"This message is usually a bit more elaborate"
```

These are then interpreted as a kind of headline (the first message) and the actual message (hidden behind ellipsis) and displayed accordingly in GitHub/GitLab.

Sometimes I'm working on Android Studio, though and I can't find an option for creating a second message in the commit dialog in the GUI. Is this not possible in the IDE or am I just not able to find it?

By the way, I think my question applies to all IntelliJ IDEs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving multiple `-m` messages, they are just concatenated by two newlines, so issuing

```
git commit -m"short message" -m"This message is usually a bit more elaborate"
```

is the same as

```
git commit -m "short message

This message is usually a bit more elaborate"
```

And this you can simply also do in any Git UI, just format the message accordingly.